# background image while flash is loading

Tags: flash

It seems that this should be a simple thing but I can't figure it out. I would just like my visitors to see a beautiful, still, jpg image in the space where my flash movie is loading...until it is fully loaded. I tried putting a background image in the cell (using Dreamweaver MX) but once I import the swf file, I can no longer see what's in the background. When I select the flash movie in MX it only allows me to select a background color, not an image. I know that I can use a preloader of some sort to let people know there is flash content loading but I would rather use the opportunity to show a professional photo.
 Do I have to set this up the same way a preloader is set up but with a single frame maybe or is there an easier way...hopefully?

Please advice Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the flash element transparent which should allow you to view the image behind it while the swf is loading:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to show the image inside Flash, with a traditional arrangement for Flash preloading. The reason you're not seeing the image you placed underneath the Flash is that Flash is typically opaque. You can make the Flash transparent by changing the render mode specified in your HTMl, but this affects performance (negatively) and isn't fully supported by all browsers (current Android browsers, for instance). So showing your image in Flash is the more robust approach, if it's available to you.

Comment: actually i made flash header and cant include navigation with the same because there are some restriction from client,so i sliced the part of image which i am using in flash and put it after the flash.by which it look like flash part,but unfortunately flash taking loading time and the sliced image come first it shows blank white space while loading flash.hope u understood what i am saying :(